# Save Email Attachment to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, vba

I receive an automated report with a big .csv file. Flow is timing out for sending the email to sharepoint. Does anyone know if I can use VBA to save certain email attachments to sharepoint?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the requirement to automate the process by listening to your inbox and then saving to SharePoint? Why VBA?

Comment: yes, that is the requirement. I know of no other solution.

Comment: how would the script know where to save it? The Subject or body of the email?

Comment: it's my understanding there are vba commands to grab the attachment from an email.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them

Comment: You can create Outlook Add-in to store email into SharePoint.

Comment: Have you considered using OneDrive for Business to do the transfer?